# Bloomberg DAPI Custom VWAP Service

Tags: c#, api, bloomberg

I am using Bloomberg DAPI with C#.
I am sending a Custom VWAP Service request //blp/mktvwap
In the response I will only get VWAP price based on the VWAP_START_TIME and the VWAP_END_TIME.
How do I get a VWAP Volume? What about other fields in the response message?
The most recent version of the Bloomberg Core API The Developer Guide has a limited information on this.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how would you get a Custom VWAP Service request with `//blp/mktvwap` but I can get `VWAP_VOLUME` using subscription.

I subscribe to an equity with the fields I want. When I add `VWAP_VOLUME` it gives me the value. If you know the field names you can subscribe all of them. I am using Python but I am pretty sure you can do the same subscriptions with C#/C++.

I am using Python, so it might not be helpful to provide my code for subscriptions but let me know if you would like to know more about subscriptions with Python.